# pygame moving square goes out of bounderies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently programming a moving square. I want to control it with my keys, and for it to not move out of bounds. However, I cannot get it to not move out of the boundaries ( the side of the window ). Here is my code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

width, height = 700, 700

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 120
x1 = 0
y1 = 0

xmb1 = False
xmf1 = False
ymb1 = False
ymf1 = False
squareh = 50
squarew = 50
squares = 3

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xmb1 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xmf1 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ymb1 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ymf1 = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xmb1 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xmf1 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ymb1 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ymf1 = False

    if x1 == 0:
        xmb1 = False
    if y1 == 0:
        ymb1 = False
    if x1 == width - squarew:
        xmfl = False
    if y1 == height - squareh:
        ymf1 == False
    if xmb1:
        x1 -= squares
    if xmf1:
        x1 += squares
    if ymb1:
        y1 -= squares
    if ymf1:
        y1 += squares
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (x1, y1, squareh, squarew), 0)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I have just recently learnt pygame(last night!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable called `xmfl` (with a lower case L) instead of `xmf1` (with a 1)

To answer your question though:

I would change this code:

```
if xmb1:
    x1 -= squares
if xmf1:
    x1 += squares
if ymb1:
    y1 -= squares
if ymf1:
    y1 += squares
```

to this

```
if xmb1 and not (x1 <= 0):
    x1 -= squares
if xmf1 and not (x1 + squarew >= width):
    x1 += squares
if ymb1 and not (y1 <= 0):
    y1 -= squares
if ymf1 and not (y1 + squareh >= height):
    y1 += squares
```

I might have the y direction backwards... its been a while since I've used pygame.

What the code does is check whether or not we're already at the edge of the board. If we are at the edge, don't allow further movement. If we aren't at the edge, go ahead.

Let me know if this helps and/or if I can answer any questions for you.